# Is there a way to lock comments? VS 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, comments

It might sound stupid, but I want to lock the comments that I made so that it cannot be edited or deleted. Is it possible to do this in Visual Studio 2017? Or is there another function besides comments/bookmarks that allow it to be locked in place?

Example:

[image]

Comment: Use source control so you can always go back to retrieve this very important commented-out code.

Comment: Can you lock sections of a text file? No. You might be able to do something really nasty with pre-commit hooks and GIT, but this is best dealt with as a coding standard that is adhered to by the team.

Comment: Ah I see. In the mean time, I'll just add it to source control in hopes that my colleagues do not accidently delete the important comments. Thanks guys!

Comment: Funny, I recently had to rewrite some old code I've written about a decade ago, found a comment saying `// TODO: Remove the following commented out code once current code checks out (some date in 2010)`....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. No version of Visual Studio offers any sort of support for making text files or portions of text files read-only.

Comment: It wouldn't really matter.  Even if VS had a feature that allowed you to add a `//--StartLockedRegion` and a `//--EndLockedRegion`, any programmer who disliked your comments could fire up Notepad and get rid of them.  Just put in an all-caps note saying `//PLEASE DO NOT REMOVE THIS BLOCK OF COMMENTS - Thanks!`

Comment: @Flydog57, I agree. Even if a VS extension was made to create this prevention, there are _way_ to many ways to bypass that protection.